# How to enable default scope for Webpart as Shared?

Tags: web-part, personalization

We can enable Shared PersonalizationScope on runtime for Webpart manager using following codebehind code:

```
if ((webpartManagerId.Personalization.Scope == PersonalizationScope.User) && (webpartManagerId.Personalization.CanEnterSharedScope))
{
    webpartManagerId.Personalization.Scope = PersonalizationScope.Shared;
}
```

I need to do this on all pages. But doing this will again [reload the Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartpersonalization.togglescope(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) to make the webpart in Shared Scope and will break other things and cause the page loading slow.

Is there any config settings, by which I can make all pages/Webpartmanagers to go in Shared scope as default?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working to make the default scope  as Shared. Rather then using `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManager` control in `.aspx` page directly. Inherit this control and set the default value in consturcted to save loading time:

```
public class CustomWebPartManager : WebPartManager
{
    public CustomWebPartManager()
    {
       Personalization.InitialScope =  PersonalizationScope.Shared;
    }
}
```